# Python3 script not running under crontab

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am used to work on AWS EC2 instances with servers on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS to launch Python3 workflows, either live to test or in crontab for scheduling.

Scripts from a github repo are launched with a Python 3.6.8 virtual environment.

Since a few weeks now, the python output is often stuck. If I run a live script with a remote ssh connection, nothing happens. I have to close the terminal window (I am using Windows WSL 1), open it again, log back in, and launch the script with the virtual env and python -v option to unblock the script output.

I have the same issue with crontabs. The python output redirected to a log file does not appear. I have empty log files.

I have checked the cron.log, nothing useful.
I have also checked syslog, nothing either.

I have the same problem with a Mac opening a remote ssh connection.
It also happens with VScode live remote ssh.

I think it really is a server side issue, but I do not where to search the issue.

Do you have a clue?

**EDIT**

For crontab without output:

```
10 10 * * * /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/repo/script.py > /home/ubuntu/repo/logs/log_script_`date "+\%Y.\%m.\%d_\%H:\%S"`.log
```

If I add -v option to Python, or even -m trace --trace, the output comes back, but only the python print() function output, not all verbosity I should have.

Once the crontab has been unblocked with -v (at least one exec), I can remove it and the output comes back in the log file, even without -v.

**EDIT 2**

I develop scripts on my laptop, and then use scp to upload it to the remote server. I have noticed that the script hangs out forever after a modification via scp.

Comment: Could you describe in common words what your scripts do? What result do you expect from it?

Comment: They interact with a Postgresql database (fetch or insert data), build dataframes with pandas, and send API calls with requests

Comment: Where is Postgres database is located? On the same server or it's different (remote) server?

Comment: Remote server : AWS RDS service

Comment: Are there error handlers in your script? It may be: no database connection, empty result from database, problem with API calls.

Comment: Each line of code is in a try except block with different error messages if the code breaks. There also is a function in except blocks that use AWS SNS to send me a mail with a traceback to show me the error details. The code runs fine I tested it many times. I just can't see what's wrong as the script, sometimes, juste hang up and does nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214890/discussion-between-vlad-and-indiaske).